# For Remedy api，whats the form name for extracting the “view the audit log” data for an incident

Tags: python, remedy

Which form name could be used to extract “view the audit log” data for an incident? for example，I can successfully extract related data using form ”HPD：help desk”，how to extract “audit log” data for an incident?

Comment: Could you kindly provide the indexed fields？ or guide me where I could find them.Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use "HPD:HelpDesk_AuditLogSystem" or "HPD:Help Desk Audit Log" form.
Regarding indexed field OOTB there is only 1 index configured- Original Request ID (ID:450).